Voximplant platform - Transfer inbound phone call to mobile number on choice
I've seen other question for the same problem, but answers are conflicting, and none works for me
I want to transfer incoming call to mobile phone, but not immediately: only IF AND WHEN user send a DTMF 3 on a select State, so I think using AppEvents.CallAlerting is not suitable for my case:
Then I tried the following solutions (fwdState is called from menuState select clicking 3)
function fwdCall(e)
{
    Call.removeEventListener(CallEvents.PlaybackFinished, fwdCall);
    const callerId=Call.callerid();
    const calledId='393333333333';
    call = VoxEngine.callPSTN(calledId, callerId);
    call.addEventListener(CallEvents.Connected, (e) => {
        VoxEngine.sendMediaBetween(e.call, Call);
    });
    
    call.addEventListener(CallEvents.Failed, VoxEngine.terminate);
    call.addEventListener(CallEvents.Disconnected, VoxEngine.terminate);        
}

function fwdCall2(e)
{
    Call.removeEventListener(CallEvents.PlaybackFinished, fwdCall2);
    const callerId=Call.callerid();
    const calledId='393333333333';
    call = VoxEngine.callPSTN(calledId, callerId,{ followDiversion: true });
    VoxEngine.easyProcess(e.call, call);
    
    call.addEventListener(CallEvents.Failed, VoxEngine.terminate);
    call.addEventListener(CallEvents.Disconnected, VoxEngine.terminate);        
}


const fwdState = new IVRState('callforward', {
        type: 'noinput',
        prompt: {
            play: 'please_wait_while_we_transfer.mp3'
        }
    }, 
    (data) => 
    {
        Call.addEventListener(CallEvents.PlaybackFinished, fwdCall);
    },
    (data) => 
    {
        fwdState.enter(Call);
    }
);

but both with fwdCall and fwdCall2 I get following error:
JS error: Call is not a constructor in /application.js:442:23

So I tested the example proposed on voximplant website HERE
but (after commenting let Call at line 3)
I get same error as above.
Which is the right way to do it?
Thanks

Well...
seems both solutions are correct and works..
in fact error is not in these functions but at the beginning of the scenario:
in all examples, voximplant uses Call as default variable to designate the call:
Call = e.call

but Call  is internally used by their routine, and when need to manage more than 1 call it returns error.
the solution is quite simple, in the first listener, that usually is
VoxEngine.addEventListener(AppEvents.CallAlerting, (e) => {

use call = e.call; instead of Call = e.call;
That's it.
